# How to identify http or https protocol using command line?

Tags: networking, protocols

I would like to check if the traffic flows through http or https protocol, using a command line tool like tcpdump or any python tool. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can track `HTTP` traffic using `tcpdump` or `tshark` (text version of Wireshark). `tcpdump` can capture whole packet contents if you use extra command line parameters like `-xx.` However, it is virtually impossible to really track `HTTPS` traffic - you will only see some encrypted packets, nothing useful.

In practice, I find more useful to use tools like `tcpflow`: it can track flow of tcp session(s) and glue all packets together into coherent view of single tcp conversation. Of course, `tcpflow` does not help with encrypted traffic either.